# Trouble with importing FBX from DAZ3D to UnrealEngine

Tags: unreal-engine4

I've placed in DAZ3D 4.7 Genesis2 Female object and exported it to the FBX (2012, 2013, 2014). After that I am trying to import it to the Unreal Engine 4.7. After import I have deformed object in UE 4.7:

[image]

How to fix this bug?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to buggy skinning data. Whether its buggy FBX, buggy Daz or buggy Unreal is not clear. The workaround is to import the FBX to 3DS Max first, then re-export it from that.